# Converting unknown JSON string to correct object

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I’m receiving an unknown string from a socket connection. It always follows the format

```
{
    “eventType”: “playerListUpdate”
    “data”: “...changes...”
}
```

I’m deserialising it using:

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NetworkMessage>(data);
```

With the *NetworkMessage* looking like this:

```
public class NetworkMessage
{
    public string data;
    public string eventType;
}
```

My problem is that sometimes the data property stays as a string, and other times it contains an array with more complex data (think DB results). So when I try to deserialise a string with an array in data, it fails.

An example of more complex data is

```
{"eventType":"latestPlayersList","data":[{"id":1,"firstName":"Harry"},{"id":2,"firstName":"Ted"},{"id":3,"firstName":"Michael"},{"id":4,"firstName":"Mike"}],"from":"server"}
```

How can I deserialise a JSON string into different VO depending on the value of *eventType*?

Comment: Show an example of the complex data please.

Comment: Ah sorry, added it in.

Comment: have you used Reflections to check types?

Comment: is the type of `data` based on the value in `eventType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deserialise is to go directly to a `JObject`

```
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
```

Now you can access property values like this:

```
var eventType = jObject.Value<string>("eventType")
```

Now you could also extend this to check the value of `eventType` and then deserialise to the right object type. So we could have a generic class like this:

```
public class NetworkMessage<T>
{
    public string EventType;
    public T Data;
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

And decide what the generic type we use based on the value of `eventType`. Note, this isn't the most efficient code in the world as it deserialises twice, but it will work:

```
private void ProcessJson(string json)
{
    var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

    switch (jObject.Value<string>("eventType"))
    {
        case "playerListUpdate":
            HandlePlayerListUpdate(jObject.ToObject<NetworkMessage<string>>());
            break;
        case "latestPlayersList":
            HandleLatestPlayersList(jObject.ToObject<NetworkMessage<List<Player>>>());
            break;
    }
}

private void HandlePlayerListUpdate(NetworkMessage<string> playerListUpdateMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Player list update: {playerListUpdateMessage.Data}");
}

private void HandleLatestPlayersList(NetworkMessage<List<Player>> latestPlayersListMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Latest Players list: {latestPlayersListMessage.Data.Count} players");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.json. Try below.

```
var files = JObject.Parse(YourJSONHere);
var recList = files.SelectTokens("$..eventType").ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < recList.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (recList[i].ToString().Contains("latestPlayersList"))
            {
                var data = files.SelectTokens("$..data").ToList();
                Console.Write(data.FirstOrDefault());
            }

            if (recList[i].ToString().Contains("playerListUpdate"))
            {
                var data = files.SelectTokens("$..data").ToList();
            }

        }
```